# How to reject ntpd query results with large delay or offsets?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

Sometimes I get large offsets when my ntpd try to sync the local clock. I think these show up as `spike_detect` in the log followed by `clock_step` because the offset is too large. These instances seem to be accompanied by rows in the peerstats file with large 'RMS jitter' of about the same magnitude as the `spike_detect`. The spike magnitudes I see are typically around 0.9s.

I think this is happening because of variable network latency. I want to avoid the up and down spikes causing my local clock to be unstable. How can I configure ntpd to drop query results where the round-trip is above a certain threshold?

It seems that ntpd already can get the numbers, as can be seen in the peerstats file but I haven't found a config item for dropping large-delay query results or something similar. chronyd has `maxdelay` for the `server` line in chrony.conf but according to the ntp.conf man page, `maxdelay` is not a thing on a `server` line in ntp.conf.

Clarification 1: I have 1 server in ntp.conf. It is a GPS-synced server that I trust to be accurate although the Internet or some firewall in the middle probably has crazy latency outliers.

Comment: How many servers do you have defined ?

Comment: @StefanSkoglund I have 1 server in the ntp.conf.

Comment: You really need at least three, this due to the fact that ntpd needs to be able to detect faulty time information.  One of three outlying = that one will be filtered and  a correct can still be averaged out of the other two.

Comment: Is the ntpd server stratum 1, it can be because of the GPS receiver, though how stable is that machine ? Though i havent used GPS receivers directly by myself. I wonder if the connection between the GPS receiver and the computer due to the computer's load could fluctuate.

Comment: If things works as it should, is your own machine stratum 2 ,then ?

Comment: The server being queried is connected directly to a GPS receiver. This is why I trust its time more than other servers that I don't control. This server is running inside a LAN with Internet port forwarding for NTP queries coming from the Internet. The machine with the problematic ntpd in question specifies this server in its ntp.conf. I don't think there's anything wrong with the GPS-connected server because another client, running chronyd, logged normal stats at around around same time when the spikes happened.

Comment: As @StefanSkoglund says, you really need three servers (or any odd number that isn't one). The other two probably won't be used for time synchronisation because your main server is Stratum 1 but they'll help with the outlier spikes